# Out of Memory when running update.php even with 512MB assigned

Tags: updating

I have the same websites on two hosters (both shared hosting)

When I tried to update the latest views module on hoster1, then I get an out of memory fatal error. I get the error even when I assign 512M or 768M with memory_limit command in the settings.php

When I tried to update the latest views module on hoster2, all works fine. There I have 256M assigned.

Can it be that there are other memory restrictions given by a hoster, which I cannot control with the assigned memory?

Thanks for any help

Comment: try putting `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` on your `settings.php`, that should override your memory limit.

Comment: What does admin/reports/status/php say?  The actual `memory_limit` will be listed.

Comment: thanks for your answers. the admin/reports/status/php says 512M, exactly as I have defined. I contacted the hoster and they said the raised the memory to 192M and this solved the problem. I don't understand why in the status/php the limit shows 512M but it only worked when the hoster changed something